# Seaborn plots are faded

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I've used seaborn plots several times from an online course. Originally plotted graphs are so different as that of my computer's. Is this because of anything on code or in graphics?

Plot on my computer:
[image: Plot on my computer.]

Original plot
[image: Original plot]

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the code being run is exactly the same, the reason would be that you are using a newer version of seaborn than the "online course".

In order to have your graphics appear in the same manner as in the online tutorial you may call

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
```